# Adding jQuery validation rules based on data- attributes in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin trying to add rules based on `data-` attributes. I'm adding min/maxlength rules based on `data-minlength` or `data-maxlength`. Here's some sample HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="input1" data-maxlength="5" data-minlength="3" required>
    <input name="input2" data-maxlength="5" required>
    <input name="input3" data-minlength="3" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm doing this to add the rules and it's working fine:

```
$('input[data-minlength]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('minlength')) {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            minlength: $(this).data('minlength')
        });
    }
});

$('input[data-maxlength]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('maxlength')) {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            maxlength: $(this).data('maxlength')
        });
    }
});
```

But I wanted to shorten it up, so I tried this and it's not working:

```
['minlength', 'maxlength'].forEach(function(item){
    $('input[data-'+item+']').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data(item)) {
            // alert(item) shows the correct rule name
            $(this).rules("add", {
                // Next line fails, but hardcoding a rule name works
                item: $(this).data(item)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The error is because `$.validator.methods[method]` is undefined. Somehow it's getting the wrong method name passed to it, even though `alert(item)` tells me the rule name is correct.

Does anyone have any idea why, or have an alternate solution I can use to shorten up the repetitive, working code above?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kaVKe/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are creating an object literal with a new property called item.

how about this?

```
['minlength', 'maxlength'].forEach(function(item){
    $('input[data-'+item+']').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data(item)) {
            // alert(item) shows the correct rule name
            var options = {};
            options[item] = $(this).data(item);

            $(this).rules("add", options);
        }
    });
});
```

This creates an options object and adds the proper property you need.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something basic. Javascript is not my strong point, I appreciate the quick explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
['minlength', 'maxlength'].forEach(function(item){
    $('input[data-'+item+']').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data(item)) {
            var rule = {};
            rule[item] = $(this).data(item);
            $(this).rules("add", rule);
        }
    });
});
```

Your solution does not work because in object literal notation, property names will not be interpreted as variables:

```
{
  item: ... // <-- this one
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. I knew it was some elementary javascript that was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply do

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var max = $(this).data('maxlength');
    var min = $(this).data('minlength')
    if (min) {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            minlength: min 
        });
    }
    if (max) {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            maxlength: max 
        });
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kaVKe/2/
Your code doesn't work i think because you can't use a variable for a property name

```
// Next line fails, item is always interpreted as item, not as maxlength/minlength
item: $(this).data(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Won't looping through every input regardless of whether it has the attribute or now be much slower than using a more specific selector? I guess I'll test it out and see.

Comment: @Madmartigan that depends on the number of inputs, it certainly might be, but also selecting inputs filtering by attribute is not that fast...you could add a class server side when an input hase at least one of those attributes and filter the input using the class

Comment: I've accepeted another answer because I think it highlights my mistake more clearly, but this might be actually what I use, because I have a couple other `data-` rules that need a little finessing so I eventually do need to cycle through more inputs. Might as well just do it once. Thanks a lot.